# Serializing an Object in a jbutton

Tags: java, swing, serialization, field

I have made a jbutton with the jframe in netbean and I want to serialize an object when i clicked the jbutton

Error :java.io.NotSerializableException: javax.swing.GroupLayout

I do not serialize any layout but why it have this error ?

```
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
getValue1 a =new getValue1();
a.name=jTextField1.getText();
a.ps=jTextField2.getText();
a.type=jComboBox1.getSelectedItem().toString();

try{
   FileOutputStream fileOut =new FileOutputStream("C:\\employee.ser");
   ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(fileOut);
   out.writeObject(a);
   out.close();
   fileOut.close();
   System.out.printf("C:\\employee.ser");
}
catch(IOException i){
        i.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public class getValue1 implements java.io.Serializable{
    public String name;
    public String ps;
    public String type;
}
```

Comment: your getValue1 might be an inner class then comes with members of enclosing class; try using a *static* inner class

Comment: @philippelhardy You're on the right track, but 'static inner' is a contradiction in terms. You should have said 'static nested'.

Comment: Thks @philippelhardy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If getValue1 (which is a bad name for a class, classes are not fields, the name should look more like Value) is part of the declaration of another class (which is an inner class) the serializer will try to serialize the parent class too.

You should move the class to a new class declaration.